# How to prevent resetting of flipclock timer in jquery?

Tags: jquery, flipclock

I have implemented a timer using jquery which is a flipclock for an exam of a website. The problem with the timer is that when the page is kept ideal for sometime without selecting options and when reloading the page, the timer gets resetted to zero. How can I prevent this ? Also I wanted to retain the timer value when the page is reloaded.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var time_min_sec = '00:00:00';

var flip = new FlipClock({
isCountdown: false,
startTime: time_min_sec,
containerElement: $('.countdown'),
});


history.pushState(null, null, location.href);
window.onpopstate = function () {
history.go(1);
};
});
```

Comment: You would need to store the current Time status someplace where the browser can check it. This could be a cookie or localStorage. Then when the page loads, it looks for that value or uses "00:00:00" if no value is found.

Comment: It's also not clear which "FlipClock" library you are using. Please include this detail or a link.

Comment: Cookies or local storage.... but nothing is preventing someone from resetting those.